# Can mongo's MR write the result to another sharded collection?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, bigdata, nosql

According to the Mongo MR documentation (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-ShardedEnvironments), the output of an MR job on sharded data CAN write the result to another sharded collection, however only the _ID can be used as the shard key.

Is there a way to emit or set the _ID that will be assigned to the resulting documents? Say use a UserID or CustomerNo which itself is used as the shard key?

Answer (score 0):

The `_id` in the documents produced by Map-Reduce is the same key that you use in `emit(...)` during the map phase. It can be of any type, including a (sub)document, but it will always be present as the `_id` field in the final documents.

If you have a target (sharded) collection using some custom value other than `ObjectId` as the value for `_id`, you can use sharded map-reduce with output into that collection.

Also there are some limitations to sharded map-reduce, notably that map-reduce will not trigger splits or migrations, and that the `limit` option is not supported.